# Pandas: how to keep in other new dataframe duplicated row from a column when value change on other column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame looking like this, df:

```
text label
a    country
a    sport
b    cooking
b    cooking
c    travel
c    design
d    tech
```

I would like to have two dataframes. One with duplicated rows from 'text' column when value on 'label' column change. And the other keeping everything else.

Expected outputs, df1:

```
text label
a    country
a    sport
c    travel
c    design
```

And df2:

```
text label
b    cooking
b    cooking
d    tech
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) for test one or multiple columns for masks:

```
m1 = df.duplicated('text', keep=False)
m2 = df.duplicated(['text','label'], keep=False)
#if all columns
#m2 = df.duplicated(keep=False)
mask = m2 | ~m1

df1 = df[~mask]
df2 = df[mask]

print (df1)
  text    label
0    a  country
1    a    sport
4    c   travel
5    c   design

print (df2)
  text    label
2    b  cooking
3    b  cooking
6    d     tech
```

Another approach is check number of unique values per groups - if equal like `1` or not:

```
mask = df.groupby('text')['label'].transform('nunique').eq(1)
df1 = df[~mask]
df2 = df[mask]
```

---

If change data ouput is different:

```
print (df)
  text    label
0    a  country
1    a    sport
2    a    sport
3    b  cooking
4    b  cooking
5    c   travel
6    c   design
7    d     tech
    

m1 = df.duplicated('text', keep=False)
m2 = df.duplicated(['text','label'], keep=False)
#if all columns
#m2 = df.duplicated(keep=False)
mask = m2 | ~m1

df1 = df[~mask]
df2 = df[mask]
print (df1)
  text    label
0    a  country
5    c   travel
6    c   design

print (df2)
  text    label
1    a    sport
2    a    sport
3    b  cooking
4    b  cooking
7    d     tech
```

---

```
mask = df.groupby('text')['label'].transform('nunique').eq(1)
df1 = df[~mask]
df2 = df[mask]
print (df1)
  text    label
0    a  country
1    a    sport
2    a    sport
5    c   travel
6    c   design

print (df2)
  text    label
3    b  cooking
4    b  cooking
7    d     tech
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
# get index of rows have duplicated `text`
duplicated = df.duplicated('text', keep=False)
duplicated_index = duplicated[duplicated == True].index

# select df1 and df2 according to this index
df1 = df.loc[duplicated_index].reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = df.loc[set(df.index) - set(duplicated_index)].reset_index(drop=True)

# we get
df1
  text    label
0    a  country
1    a    sport
2    c   travel
3    c  designe

df2
  text    label
0    b  cooking
1    d     tech
```